# Can I prevent previews of images in Finder?

Tags: finder

I often upload images to the internet, and doing so is always a pain. The Finder's Open/Choose dialogue takes over 5 seconds to load image previews, regardless of the size of the image (very small screenshot pngs take the same amount of time as 8MB jpeg photos). While waiting for the preview to load the whole window locks up so I can't click 'Open' until the preview has loaded.

Is there a way of preventing image previews from displaying in the column Finder view, or stopping them hanging the upload Finder window?

Chrome, Mavericks, 2012 Macbook (non-retina) 15"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can disable the image previews on Finder.

Right-click on the folder and select "Show View Options."

A long window will appear. On the 5th group from the top, you should see a checkmark called "Show icon preview". Deselect it.

[image]

Once you are done, select the "Use as Defaults" bottom, which is located at the bottom of the window.

Comment: Interestingly I got a checkbox called 'Show preview column', which I disabled. Can I do it globally for all folders?

Comment: Yes. I've edited the answer; I forgot to add a step.